# network timeout exception in android

Tags: java, android

I developed android app and tested in Samsung tab 2.The code fetch the data from java server page which hosted in server.It works day before,but now it shows network time out exception during `urlConnection.getInputStream()` .I d't change anything in my code. pls help me to overcome the error.

```
try {

     String tally_ipaddr="XXXXXXX";
     URL url = new URL(tally_ipaddr+"/Iplogin.jsp");
     urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     String line = "";       
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
       sb.append(line);
     }
 Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (Exception e)  {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you reach the server outside of your code? Like, in a web browser?

Comment: its happend when your server is too slow or internet.

Comment: @KenWolf  ya..I tested in browser,I works and I've high speed wi-fi.

Comment: @user2470014 Samsung tab 2 is using the same Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: @KenWolf I've separate Wi-Fi modem to tab.separate wired modem for PC.and I also check with 3G sim.

Comment: @user2470014 can you access the site from the browser on the tab? Also, it says `IPlogin.jsp`. Are you doing IP-based login? Has the tab's IP address changed? Anything happen if it's the "wrong" ip address?

Comment: @KenWolf no,I can't access site from the browser.i think it may be problem in my web server..

Answer (score 0):

```
class UrlFetch extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            String tally_ipaddr="XXXXXXX";

            URL url = new URL(tally_ipaddr+"/Iplogin.jsp");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);    // 5 seconds
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");       
            conn.connect();
            BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            conn.disconnect(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

}
```

and call the asynctask like given below

```
new UrlFetch().execute();
```

Hope the above code will works for you

Answer (score 0):

I notice the address ends with "Iplogin.jsp".

Make sure the server is accepting connections from the IP address of your device. I think the IP address of your device has changed and the server is no longer responding to requests from that device.

The fact that you can access the service from your desktop browser but NOT from the device browser is highly suspect.

Comment: My PC have public IP, hence i can access the jsp file in any sytem that connect in LAN.But I c't get the response(ping in cmd prompt) from the server.What's the prob?..

Comment: @user2470014 work with your server/network admin to solve this problem :) Or give me access to the server and your source.

Comment: At last I clear the exception by change the internet properties in my pc. Disable client for MS Network in the IPV4 properties.tnx all for help me.